# Yii2 POST method does not display the view

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, yii2

I'm trying to call a view through the post method, without results. Sending the POST request via ajax or actionPOST does not execute the view.
I need an example that runs my view through the post method.

```
Code below

<script>

     function sendPost() {
        $.ajax({
           type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo yii::$app->geturlmanager()->createurl('site/upload'); ?>",
            data: {name:'Keth',_csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'},
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

</script>


controller  site

public actionPost()
{
    $name = 'Bart';
    Yii::$app->runAction(['site/upload','name' => $name]);  

}

public function actionUpload()
{
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)  {
            $name = Yii::$app->request->post('name');
        }else
        {

            $name = Yii::$app->request->post('name');
            return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($flag);
        }

    $model = new SiteUploadForm();

     return $this->render('site-upload', [
                'model' => $model,
                'name' => $name ]); 

}

view site

echo $name
```

Comment: Which response do you get when you execute `sendPost()` method?

Comment: Ok ajax in the inspector chrome.
No results in code and no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your function declaration is wrong, change this:

```
public actionPost()
{
    $name = 'Bart';
    Yii::$app->runAction(['site/upload','name' => $name]);  

}
```

to:

```
public function actionPost()
{
    $name = 'Bart';
    Yii::$app->runAction(['site/upload','name' => $name]);  

}
```

IDE should mark this as invalid.

Comment: No results yet.

Comment: So what response you get in ajax request? (Chrome Developer Tools -> Network)

Comment: Yes in ajax request or by yii2 model